# Aligns Labels with items in a JavaFX ListVies

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a page in my application that contains a ListView, at the top of this ListView I want to put labels that tell what each column contains, but it's misaligned with the ListView and I'm at a loss as to how to align it in a responsive way.

[image]

Adding the ListView and my subtitle HBox, here there is the getLegend method that adds the subtitle:

```
        AnchorPane listLegend = getListLegend(16);
        VBox.setMargin(listLegend, new Insets(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        Separator separator = new Separator();
        separator.setPrefWidth(200.0);
        VBox.setMargin(separator, new Insets(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        assetsListView = new ListView<>();
        assetsListView.getStyleClass().add("scroll");

        VBox.setVgrow(assetsListView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setMargin(assetsListView, new Insets(5.0,0,0,0));

        contentVBox.getChildren().addAll(assetsLabel, newAssetButton, listLegend, assetsListView);

        scrollPaneContentAnchorPane.getChildren().add(contentVBox);

        //mainScrollPane.setContent(scrollPaneContentAnchorPane);

        assetsStructVBox.getChildren().addAll(assetsTopCardsHBox, scrollPaneContentAnchorPane);
        getChildren().add(assetsStructVBox);
```

```
private AnchorPane getListLegend(int fontSize){
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        HBox mainHBox = new HBox();

        mainHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);

        AnchorPane assetImageAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(assetImageAnchorPane, Priority.NEVER);

        HBox assetImageHBox = new HBox();

        assetImageHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);

        ImageView assetImageView = new ImageView();

        assetImageView.setFitWidth(30); assetImageView.setFitHeight(30);

        assetImageHBox.getChildren().add(assetImageView);
        assetImageAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(assetImageHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(assetImageAnchorPane, new Insets(0,0,0,10));

        AnchorPane assetNameAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(assetNameAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox assetNameHBox = new HBox();

        assetNameHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);

        Label nameLabel = new Label("Nome");
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font(fontSize));

        nameLabel.setPrefWidth(80);
        nameLabel.setMaxWidth(80);

        assetNameHBox.getChildren().add(nameLabel);
        assetNameAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(assetNameHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(assetNameAnchorPane, new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0));

        AnchorPane modelLabelAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(modelLabelAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox modelLabelHBox = new HBox();

        modelLabelHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);

        Label modelLabel = new Label("Modelo");
        modelLabel.setFont(new Font(fontSize));

        modelLabel.setPrefWidth(80);
        modelLabel.setMaxWidth(80);

        modelLabelHBox.getChildren().add(modelLabel);
        modelLabelAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(modelLabelHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(modelLabelAnchorPane, new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        AnchorPane downtimeLabelAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(downtimeLabelAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox downtimeLabelHBox = new HBox();

        downtimeLabelHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);

        Label downtimeLabel = new Label("Downtime");
        downtimeLabel.setFont(new Font(fontSize));

        downtimeLabel.setPrefWidth(80);
        downtimeLabel.setMaxWidth(80);

        downtimeLabelHBox.getChildren().add(downtimeLabel);
        downtimeLabelAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(downtimeLabelHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(downtimeLabelAnchorPane, new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        AnchorPane statusBadgeAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(statusBadgeAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox statusBadgeHBox = new HBox();

        statusBadgeHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);

        Label status = new Label("Estado");
        status.setFont(new Font(fontSize));

        statusBadgeAnchorPane.setPrefWidth(130);
        statusBadgeAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(130);

        statusBadgeHBox.getChildren().add(status);
        statusBadgeAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(statusBadgeHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(statusBadgeAnchorPane, new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        AnchorPane actionButtonsAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(actionButtonsAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox actionButtonsHBox = new HBox();

        actionButtonsHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);

        Label action = new Label("Ações");
        action.setFont(new Font(fontSize));

        actionButtonsHBox.getChildren().add(action);
        actionButtonsAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(actionButtonsHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(actionButtonsAnchorPane, new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        assetImageAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        assetNameAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        modelLabelAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        downtimeLabelAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        statusBadgeAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        actionButtonsAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        mainHBox.getChildren().addAll(
                assetImageAnchorPane,
                assetNameAnchorPane,
                modelLabelAnchorPane,
                downtimeLabelAnchorPane,
                statusBadgeAnchorPane,
                actionButtonsAnchorPane
        );

        root.setMaxHeight(30);
        root.getChildren().addAll(mainHBox);

        return root;
    }
```

My items that are added to the list look like this:

```
public void renderCell(
            String name,
            String model,
            String downtime,
            AssetState state
    ){
        HBox mainHBox = new HBox();

        mainHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(mainHBox, 0.0);

        AnchorPane assetImageAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(assetImageAnchorPane, Priority.NEVER);

        HBox assetImageHBox = new HBox();

        assetImageHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(assetImageHBox, 0.0);

        ImageView assetImageView = new ImageView(new Image(MSPM.class.getResource("/mspm/icons/default/motor-eletrico.png").toString()));

        assetImageView.setFitWidth(30); assetImageView.setFitHeight(30);

        assetImageHBox.getChildren().add(assetImageView);
        assetImageAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(assetImageHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(assetImageAnchorPane, new Insets(0,0,0,10));

        AnchorPane assetNameAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(assetNameAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox assetNameHBox = new HBox();

        assetNameHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(assetNameHBox, 0.0);

        Label nameLabel = new Label(name);
        Tooltip.install(nameLabel, new CustomToolTip(name));

        nameLabel.setPrefWidth(80);
        nameLabel.setMaxWidth(80);

        assetNameHBox.getChildren().add(nameLabel);
        assetNameAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(assetNameHBox);

        AnchorPane modelLabelAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(modelLabelAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox modelLabelHBox = new HBox();

        modelLabelHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(modelLabelHBox, 0.0);

        Label modelLabel = new Label(model);
        Tooltip.install(modelLabel, new CustomToolTip(model));

        modelLabel.setPrefWidth(80);
        modelLabel.setMaxWidth(80);

        modelLabelHBox.getChildren().add(modelLabel);
        modelLabelAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(modelLabelHBox);

        AnchorPane downtimeLabelAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(downtimeLabelAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox downtimeLabelHBox = new HBox();

        downtimeLabelHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(downtimeLabelHBox, 0.0);

        Label downtimeLabel = new Label(downtime);
        Tooltip.install(downtimeLabel, new CustomToolTip(downtime));

        downtimeLabel.setPrefWidth(80);
        downtimeLabel.setMaxWidth(80);

        downtimeLabelHBox.getChildren().add(downtimeLabel);
        downtimeLabelAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(downtimeLabelHBox);

        AnchorPane statusBadgeAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(statusBadgeAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox statusBadgeHBox = new HBox();

        statusBadgeHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(statusBadgeHBox, 0.0);

        Badge statusBadge = new Badge("", BadgeStyle.INFO);

        Tooltip.install(statusBadge, new CustomToolTip("Indica o estado do ativo"));

        if(state == AssetState.IDLE) {
            statusBadge.getLabel().setText(AssetState.IDLE.getLegend());
            statusBadge.setBadgeStyle(BadgeStyle.DANGER);
        }else{
            statusBadge.getLabel().setText(AssetState.WORKING.getLegend());
            statusBadge.setBadgeStyle(BadgeStyle.SUCCESS);
        }

        statusBadge.setPrefWidth(130);
        statusBadge.setMaxWidth(130);

        statusBadgeHBox.getChildren().add(statusBadge);
        statusBadgeAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(statusBadgeHBox);

        AnchorPane actionButtonsAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(actionButtonsAnchorPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        actionButtonsAnchorPane.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {isClickInActions = true;});
        //actionButtonsAnchorPane.setOnMouseExited(event -> {isClickInActions = false;});

        HBox actionButtonsHBox = new HBox();

        actionButtonsHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(actionButtonsHBox, 0.0);

        CustomButton editButton = new CustomButton("",
                new Image(MSPM.class.getResource("/mspm/icons/edit.png").toString()),
                "",
                (int) 15.0
        );

        Tooltip.install(editButton, new CustomToolTip("Editar ativo"));

        HBox.setMargin(editButton, new Insets(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0));

        editButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                onClickInEditButton(event);
            }
        });

        CustomButton manualDowntimeButton = new CustomButton("",
                new Image(MSPM.class.getResource("/mspm/icons/clock.png").toString()),
                "",
                (int) 15.0
        );
        Tooltip.install(manualDowntimeButton, new CustomToolTip("Alterar estado do ativo"));

        HBox.setMargin(manualDowntimeButton, new Insets(0.0,5.0,0.0,5.0));

        manualDowntimeButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                onClickInModifyButton(event);
            }
        });

        CustomButton deleteButton = new CustomButton("",
                new Image(MSPM.class.getResource("/mspm/icons/trash.png").toString()),
                "",
                (int) 15.0
        );
        Tooltip.install(deleteButton, new CustomToolTip("Deletar ativo"));

        deleteButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                onClickInDeleteButton(event);
            }
        });

        HBox.setMargin(deleteButton, new Insets(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0));

        actionButtonsHBox.getChildren().addAll(editButton, manualDowntimeButton, deleteButton);
        actionButtonsAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(actionButtonsHBox);

        HBox.setMargin(actionButtonsAnchorPane, new Insets(0.0,10.0,0.0,0.0));

        actionButtonsAnchorPane.setPrefWidth(40);
        actionButtonsAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(40);

        assetImageAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        assetNameAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        modelLabelAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        downtimeLabelAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        statusBadgeAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        actionButtonsAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        mainHBox.getChildren().addAll(
                assetImageAnchorPane,
                assetNameAnchorPane,
                modelLabelAnchorPane,
                downtimeLabelAnchorPane,
                statusBadgeAnchorPane,
                actionButtonsAnchorPane
        );

        root.setMaxHeight(30);
        root.getChildren().addAll(mainHBox);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using TableView? I strongly suggest you go through the layouts in JavaFX. For me it looks like you are making it a bit more complicated.

Comment: Wrapping many elements in AnchorPanes is a very strange thing to do.  I don't know why you do that.

Comment: For complex layouts, I suggest at least prototyping using [SceneBuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) with its preview feature, even if you decide not to use FXML in the end.

Comment: I'm using ListView because the stock column has buttons.
And the anchorpanes actually serve to use the Hgrow ALWAYS, so it stretches according to the page and I put another HBox inside to use the center alignment.

Comment: You can still achieve the requirement using TableView. And I think  you can even make it simpler by not using AnchorPane and using other available panes. Please  provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can guide you how you can achieve that.

Comment: Use a `TableView`. This is exactly the use case it is designed for.

Comment: *the anchorpanes actually serve to use the Hgrow ALWAYS, so it stretches according to the page:* -> You don't need an AnchorPane to achieve that result.

Comment: I replaced my ListViews with tableView, it was a lot of work, but the result was much better. Does anyone know how I can center the cell labels?
How can I replace the Anchors? Maybe use Pane?

Comment: Create a small app that demos your current issue. You should probably not use `AnchorPane` or `Pane` in your `TableView` cells. I would have to see the exact code to give better advice. Without seeing the code, I would suggest `VBox` or `HBox` depending on the situation.

Comment: In your screenshot, the cells in most columns just contain a single label. You shouldn't even need custom cells for that, and I believe you should be able to change the alignment with a simple piece of CSS. If this is a lot of work, you are doing it wrong. Create and post a [mre] showing what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments under the question, this is the perfect use case for `TableView`. It has labeled columns and aligns the values of each column for you. If you need to customize how a particular column renders its cells (e.g., displaying a set of "action buttons"), then you can set a `cellFactory` to return custom `TableCell` implementations. And although I don't know if you're using a library such as *MaterialFX*, it is possible to style a default `TableView` to look like what you're attempting via CSS.

Here is an example.

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static String dataUriStylesheet() {
        // 'STYLESHEET' is defined at the bottom of this class
        return "data:text/css," + STYLESHEET;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);

        var titleBox = new HBox(new Label("Assets"), spacer, new Button("New Asset"));
        titleBox.getStyleClass().add("title-box");

        var table = new TableView<Asset>();
        table.getItems().addAll(createDummyAssets());
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_FLEX_LAST_COLUMN);
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Name", Asset::name, null));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Model", Asset::model, null));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Downtime", Asset::downtime, null));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("State", Asset::state, null));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Actions", Function.identity(), AssetActionsTableCell::new));
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);

        var card = new VBox(titleBox, table);
        card.getStyleClass().add("card");

        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(card), 1200, 720);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(dataUriStylesheet());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Asset View");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private List<Asset> createDummyAssets() {
        return List.of(
                new Asset("Test 001", "Foo", 8, Asset.State.RUNNING),
                new Asset("Test 002", "Foo", 0, Asset.State.STOPPED),
                new Asset("Test 003", "Bar", 4, Asset.State.RUNNING),
                new Asset("Test 004", "Bar", 42, Asset.State.DOWN));
    }

    // A helper method for creating TableColumns with a record as the model type
    private <T> TableColumn<Asset, T> createColumn(
            String text, Function<Asset, T> valueFactory, Supplier<TableCell<Asset, T>> cellFactory) {
        var column = new TableColumn<Asset, T>(text);
        column.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
            var propertyValue = valueFactory.apply(data.getValue());
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(propertyValue);
        });
        if (cellFactory != null) {
            column.setCellFactory(tc -> cellFactory.get());
        }
        return column;
    }

    // Using a record to make implementing the example less verbose. In a real application,
    // it is likely Asset would be a so-called "JavaFX Bean", which means defining and exposing
    // actual JavaFX properties (e.g., StringProperty for the name), though only if you need
    // to support mutability.
    public record Asset(String name, String model, double downtime, State state) {
        public enum State {
            RUNNING,
            STOPPED,
            DOWN
        }
    }

    public static class AssetActionsTableCell extends TableCell<Asset, Asset> {

        private final Node graphic;

        // In a real application you'd pass some kind of callback as part of
        // implementing the buttons' on-action handlers.
        public AssetActionsTableCell() {
            graphic = new HBox(new Button("Edit"), new Button("Delete"));
            graphic.getStyleClass().add("button-box");

            getStyleClass().add("asset-actions-table-cell");
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Asset item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(graphic);
            }
        }
    }

    private static final String STYLESHEET =
            """
            .root {
                -fx-padding: 35;
            }
            
            .card {
                -fx-padding: 10;
                -fx-spacing: 10;
                -fx-background-color: white;
                -fx-background-radius: 5;
                -fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box, gray, 10, 0.4, 0, 0);
            }
            
            .card .title-box {
                -fx-alignment: center_left;
            }
            
            .card .title-box .label {
                -fx-font: bold 24pt "System";
            }
            
            .table-view,
            .table-row-cell,
            .table-cell,
            .table-column,
            .column-header-background {
                -fx-background-color: transparent;
            }
            
            .column-header {
                -fx-font: bold 12pt "System";
                -fx-border-color: black;
                -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
            }
            
            .table-row-cell {
                -fx-padding: 10 10 10 0;
            }
            
            .table-row-cell:selected {
                -fx-background-color: lightgray;
                -fx-background-radius: 20;
                -fx-background-insets: 5 10 5 0;
            }
            
            .table-row-cell:selected .table-cell {
                -fx-text-fill: black;
            }
            
            .table-cell {
                -fx-alignment: center;
                -fx-border-color: null;
                -fx-padding: 0;
            }
            
            .asset-actions-table-cell .button-box {
                -fx-alignment: center;
                -fx-spacing: 10;
            }
            """;
}
```

Note this example is only a *proof-of-concept*.

- It does not implement functionality for any of the buttons.
- It does not implement all the features of your screenshot (e.g., no icon column, no styling of the "State" column, etc.).
- It does not necessarily demonstrate best practices, particularly regarding real-world application structure.

Though it does demonstrate a better use of layouts. It is typically best to use layouts which size and position their children *relatively* in a responsive way. If one such layout cannot give you what you want, then often a *combination* of such layouts is the answer (instead of e.g., `AnchorPane`).

Also, to make running the example easier, the CSS is defined as a multiline string and added to the scene via a data URI (this requires JavaFX 17+). For convenience, here is the CSS separately:

```css
.root {
    -fx-padding: 35;
}

.card {
    -fx-padding: 10;
    -fx-spacing: 10;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-radius: 5;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box, gray, 10, 0.4, 0, 0);
}

.card .title-box {
    -fx-alignment: center_left;
}

.card .title-box .label {
    -fx-font: bold 24pt "System";
}

.table-view,
.table-row-cell,
.table-cell,
.table-column,
.column-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.column-header {
    -fx-font: bold 12pt "System";
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
}

.table-row-cell {
    -fx-padding: 10 10 10 0;
}

.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: lightgray;
    -fx-background-radius: 20;
    -fx-background-insets: 5 10 5 0;
}

.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.table-cell {
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-border-color: null;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.asset-actions-table-cell .button-box {
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-spacing: 10;
}
```

Note I do not guarantee the above CSS is the most efficient or otherwise best way of implementing the desired look.

Here is a screenshot of the example:

[image: screenshot of example]

Note I moved the "New Assets" button to the same level as the "Assets" label and put it to the right of the card. I believe this better utilizes the vertical space of the UI, but you can of course keep the button where you currently have it if you prefer. The gray "bar" in the table is how selected rows are styled in the example; obviously, you can also remove or change this as desired.